# Required prop `visibleTodos[0].text` was not specified in `App`

Tags: reactjs, redux

Please i am trying the example [Here](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) as a react-react tutorial. The code works , however, when `onTodoClick` fails with the following error

`Warning: Failed propType: Required prop`visibleTodos[0].text`was not specified in`App`. Check the render method of`Connect(App)`.`

`Warning: Failed propType: Required prop`todos[0].text`was not specified in`TodoList`. Check the render method of`App`.`

Below is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        // Injected by connect() call:
    const { dispatch, visibleTodos, visibilityFilter } = this.props
        return (
          <div>
                <AddTodo
                    onAddClick={text =>
                    dispatch(addTodo(text))
              } />
                <TodoList
                    todos={visibleTodos}
                    onTodoClick={id =>
                    dispatch(completeTodo(id))
              } />
                <Footer
                    filter={visibilityFilter}
                    onFilterChange={nextFilter =>
                    dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(nextFilter))
              } />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
App.propTypes = {
  visibleTodos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
  visibilityFilter: PropTypes.oneOf([
    'SHOW_ALL',
    'SHOW_COMPLETED',
    'SHOW_ACTIVE'
  ]).isRequired
}

function selectTodos(todos, filter) {
  switch (filter) {
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
      return todos
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
      return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
    case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
      return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
  }
}

function select(state) {
  return {
    visibleTodos: selectTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter),
    visibilityFilter: state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

export default connect(select)(App)
```

and my TodoList

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

export default class TodoList extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.props.todos.map((todo, index) =>
                    <Todo {...todo}
                        key={index}
                        onClick={() => this.props.onTodoClick(index)} />
                )}

            </ul>
        )
    }
}

TodoList.propTypes = {
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired
}
```

When i run my app. I was able to add a an item to the todo list. However, when click on the todoItem, The text disappear and the two warnings above shows in the console.

After studying the warnings. I removed the two text props declarations like

```
TodoList.propTypes = {
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired
}
```

And

```
App.propTypes = {
  visibleTodos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
 ......
}
```

After which , the warning disappear . However , my todoItem disappear `onTodoClick` . Please ho do i addressed this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am doing the same tutorial crashing in the same warning.

From the source code I can see that `todos[0].id` is specified correctly:

   TodoList.propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired).isRequired,

So you cannot remove the `id` put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is due to that no `id` is generated for a `todo` item. So the warning is correct and is telling what is missing correctly.

In `reducers.js` add for example `id: Math.random()` and your warning will dissapear.

Whole reducer function:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
        return [
            ...state,
            {
                text: action.text,
                completed: false,
                id: Math.random()
            }
        ]
    // other cases 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone...

I was following the same tutorial today and ran across this answer. Plugging a number into the `ADD_TODO` fixes the error mentioned above, but the `TOGGLE_TODO` still wasn't working for me.

I don't know if this is the world's best fix but I got the toggle working when I moved down a few lines in the same *reducers.js* file, to the `case TOGGLE_TODO` bit, and changed the `if` statement inside the `state.map` function to read:

`if (todo.id === action.id) { return Object.assign... }`